Why only two polarisation states of the EM wave in the Jeans cube are considered?
This question already has answers here and there.
But none of them answers , why there are only two polarisation states for a mode in the Jeans cube ?
I mean they only say that we take the two polarisation as perpendicular to each other along the axes

Another technical problem is that you can have waves polarized in two perpendicular planes, so we must multiply by two to account for that.

but my doubt is that the wave would very well exist even when we take any other of the infinite direction of Electric field along with the corresponding perpendicular Magnetic field on the plane.
So why take only two of them?
Please give an answer without using the Hamiltonian and in a simple mathematical or intuitive language.
For someone not getting the term:

Jeans cube is a fair approximation of a blackbody through which (generally) the Rayleigh - Jeans criteria of Blackbody radiation is derived.


I don't really see the relation of this question to the other linked questions, perhaps instead link to a derivation of what you mean by Jeans cube instead?

@Triatticus Jeans cube is a fair approximation of a blackbody through which (generally) the Rayleigh - Jeans criteria of Blackbody radiation is derived.

You should put this information into the question, not everyone knows what this might be, if you have a derivation which shows them assuming something about the polarizations then include it if possible. You may even have to just type it up yourself.

This is because the Rayleigh-Jeans derivation works with several assumptions, where the two most apparent ones are:

the EM radiation energy can be expressed as sum of squares of some physical quantities;
the standard results of statistical physics apply to EM radiation, mainly the equipartition theorem: each system state coordinate or momentum that appears as square (second power) in additive terms in the expression of energy of the system of temperature $T$, contributes to net average energy with value $k_BT/2$. For example, ideal gas with $N$ molecules with no internal structure has three squares of momentum variables per any single molecule $a$:

$$
E = ... + \frac{p_{a,x}^2}{2m} + \frac{p_{a,y}^2}{2m} + \frac{p_{a,z}^2}{2m}+...
$$
thus there are total $3N$ squares in the expression of energy of this ideal gas. Equipartition says each term contributes average energy $\frac{1}{2}k_BT$, thus average total kinetic energy of the gas is $\frac{3}{2}Nk_BT$.
The first assumption is true if EM radiation energy is assumed to be given by the Poynting formulae, and we express the Poynting energy in terms of the Fourier coefficients that together represent the electric and magnetic field everywhere in the cuboid.
It turns out that to describe completely all possible EM field configurations in the cuboid, we need two numbers for each Fourier mode (wave with a definite wave vector $\mathbf k$). This is due to fact that vector potential $\mathbf A$, due to chosen gauge and due to Maxwell's equations, lies in the plane perpendicular to $\mathbf k$, and thus always has zero component in direction of $\mathbf k$. Thus to fully describe length and direction of this vector, given we already know $\mathbf k$, we need only two real numbers, to give two components of the vector in the plane and given vector base (which is arbitrary, but always has two members). Thus for each Fourier mode, we have not one, but two quadratic terms in the expression for energy. (Actually, we have four, because we have two for coordinates $A_1,A_2$ and two for momenta $B_1,B_2$).
Then the second assumption is used: each quadratic term in the expression for EM energy contributes $k_BT/2$. Thus each component of $ A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2$ in the plane perpendicular to $\mathbf k$ contributes average energy $k_BT/2$, thus total contribution per one wave-vector is $2k_BT$. There are no other terms for all possible directions of $\mathbf A$, because in energy we do not have a term for each direction in the plane, but we have a term for each linearly independent direction in the plane, and there are only two. Similarly in the gas, we do not have infinity of terms $\frac{p_{a,\mathbf t}^2}{2m}$ for all possible directions of motion $\mathbf t$, but only three, because there are only three linearly independent directions in 3D space. In EM waves, there are only two linearly independent directions in "polarization space".
These assumptions lead to absurd result, that EM radiation either cannot be in state of thermodynamic equilibrium, or it has infinite energy in this state, and any hole in the cuboid would result in a beam of radiation with infinite intensity. The conclusion that offers itself is that at least one, but perhaps both assumptions are wrong for EM radiation in thermodynamic equilibrium.

So , you are saying that ( in simple terms) all the infinite directions of polarization could be constructed using the two independent polarisation states. And since each of the independent one has average energy, kT and hence the wave which we get by their superposition has average energy 2kT.Am I right?

The coordinate of any wave (in the spatial Fourier domain) with a wave vector $\mathbf k$ can be expressed as linear combination $c_1 \mathbf F_{\mathbf k,1} + c_2 \mathbf F_{\mathbf k,2}$ of two independent terms with the same $\mathbf k$, differing in their polarization. In the linear combination there are two real variables $c_1,c_2$ and each contributes $k_B T/2$ to the expected average energy. The same is true for the momentum variables, thus any $\mathbf k$ contributes total $2k_B T$ to the average.
